# How do I add label values to wait commands?

Tags: ios, swift, delay, iphone-vibrate

I am making an app that vibrates with customizable breaks in between. I have a slider that is numbered 0-50. And it rounds it to the closest integer then displays it in my label. I am now trying to execute the command:

```
@IBOutlet weak var amount: UILabel!

@IBAction func slider1(_ sender: UISlider) {

    amount.text = String(Int(sender.value));

}

@IBAction func vibrator(_ sender: UISlider) {

   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)

    (the wait goes here but I don't know how to add it)
}
```

also if possible in the wait command i want to divide the label value by 10.
it doesn't have to be specifically the wait command, just something to delay it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` accepts a block which can run after a specified time. Get the slider value and pass it. It would help if you could break what you want to achieve into smaller steps.

Comment: So how would I type that?

Comment: Please read the documentation, that would help you get a better understanding

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to do this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1.0) {
    // this runs after a 1.0 second wait.
}
```

In this example, the code inside the function runs after an amount of time declared here:

```
DispatchTime.now() + 1.0
```

The 1.0 is the time in seconds to wait, essentially.  I'm assuming from what you said, you'll want to change that bit of code to:

```
DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int(amount.text)! / 10)
```

I hope this is the answer you were looking for!

Comment: Ok I did exactly that and now it says "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"    And it is underlining the "t" in the word "text"       Please Help!

Comment: Oh yeah, change that to: `DispatchTime.now() + (Int(amount.text!)! / 10)`, should work.

Comment: Now, it says. "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DispatchTime' and 'Int'  "    What do I do Now?

Comment: Try `DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int(amount.text)! / 10)`, sorry I haven't actually tested it. I'll test it once I get home.